# How to make a set of 3-D bar plots with absolute correlation values being the height?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am reading a paper and trying to reproduce a result. A table of coefficients is given as below:
[image]

I am trying plot a 3-D correlation graph in Python ,with the height being the absolute correlation values. The graph should look like the following:

[image]

I'm really bad at creating 3-D plots in Python. Can someone give me a hint? What should I do after creating an array of values containing all the estimated values as shown in the table?

Below is my code so far:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
plt.style.use('classic')
%matplotlib inline
from mpl_toolkits import mplot3d
import math

a = np.array([1.2797,0.2021,4.2635,0,0.0402,0.0005,0.0072,0.0401,0.1141,0.0369,0.1713]) #coefficients as shown in the table

def correlationCoefficient(X, Y, n) :
    sum_X = 0
    sum_Y = 0
    sum_XY = 0
    squareSum_X = 0
    squareSum_Y = 0
     
     
    i = 0
    while i < n :
        # sum of elements of array X.
        sum_X = sum_X + X[i]
         
        # sum of elements of array Y.
        sum_Y = sum_Y + Y[i]
         
        # sum of X[i] * Y[i].
        sum_XY = sum_XY + X[i] * Y[i]
         
        # sum of square of array elements.
        squareSum_X = squareSum_X + X[i] * X[i]
        squareSum_Y = squareSum_Y + Y[i] * Y[i]
         
        i = i + 1
      
    # use formula for calculating correlation
    # coefficient.
    corr = (float)(n * sum_XY - sum_X * sum_Y)/ \
           (float)(math.sqrt((n * squareSum_X -\
           sum_X * sum_X)* (n * squareSum_Y -\
           sum_Y * sum_Y)))
    return corr
n = len(a)
for i,j in zip(range(n),range(n)):
    print(correlationCoefficient(a[i], a[j], n))
```

However, an error occurred while I'm trying to get the list of correlation values between each element in array `a` and itself.

```
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-34-1da37dfbf060> in <module>
      1 n = len(a)
      2 for i,j in zip(range(n),range(n)):
----> 3     print(correlationCoefficient(a[i], a[j], n))

<ipython-input-29-bad7954120c0> in correlationCoefficient(X, Y, n)
     10     while i < n :
     11         # sum of elements of array X.
---> 12         sum_X = sum_X + X[i]
     13 
     14         # sum of elements of array Y.

IndexError: invalid index to scalar variable.
```

Comment: Can we see the code you already have?

Comment: I don't have much code yet.. I only know how to create a 2-D histogram, so I have no clue where to start this

Answer (score 1):

You may want to consider explore `plot_surface()` in `matplotlib.pyplot`.